# How to access Django relations outside the django?

Tags: python, django, orm, external

I have small project in django in which I need to access Django relations outside the Django project.

I would like to get querySet of all logs related to player via command like player.logs.all().
Getting querySet through player.logs.all() works when I do it in django shell and when I do it in views.py, but it does not work from external file even when I set up django connection properly

models.py

```
class Log(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  link = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
  
  class Meta:
    app_label = 'stats'
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Player(models.Model):
  logs = models.ManyToManyField(Log)
  name = models.TextField()
  steamid3 = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)

  class Meta:
    app_label = 'stats'

  def __str__(self):
    return self.steamid3
```

external test.py

```
import django

from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        },
        'NAME': 'stats',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
)
django.setup()

from stats.models import *

l = Log.objects.all()  #Works
players = Player.objects.all() #Works
player = Player.objects.get(pk='[U:1:92778910]') #Works
print(player.logs.all()) #Does not work
```

Error I get after running test.py

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'player' into field. Choices are: link, name
```

Comment: what does the output of `player = Player.objects.get(pk='[U:1:92778910]')` produce? using `print(player)`

Comment: It produces [U:1:92778910]. But the exact line "player.logs.all()" works in shell when I do everything the same.

Comment: error indicates you are on a log object. what happens with `print(player.name)`

Comment: it prints a name which is "cieniu97"

Comment: guessing now. does `player.log_set.all()` work?

Comment: I tried that before. Unfortunatly - AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'logs_set'. The problem isn't in line "player.logs.all()", because it works in views.py and in django shell. This is something about access to relations or configuring connection with django

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Instead of manually configuring settings one need to import original django settings. Like shown below

test.py

```
import django
import os

from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tf2stats.settings")
django.setup()

from stats.models import *

player = Player.objects.get(pk='[U:1:100146668]')

print(player.logs.all())
```